# Why do pandas generate a figure handle for each group when we plot a dataframe after a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
date    region  Re
2020-02-25  AG  1.36    
2020-02-26  AG  1.53    
2020-02-27  AG  1.6 
2020-02-28  AG  1.88    
2020-02-29  AG  2.09    
2020-02-25  FR  2.33    
2020-02-26  FR  2.54    
2020-02-27  FR  2.61    
2020-02-28  FR  2.68    
2020-02-29  FR  2.69
```

Now if I run:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the data from clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# Set a new index
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Plot the result grouped by region
h = df.groupby('region')['Re'].plot(rot=90)
```

I get my plot. But `h` is a pandas Series that contains two `AxesSubPlot` object:

```
region
AG    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
FR    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.755)
Name: Re, dtype: object
```

So for example if I would like to change the `ylim` I cannot simply write `h.set_ylim((0,3))`. Why pandas produce a figure handle for each group, why is it useful ? Could I even use the `set_ylim` method in such a case ?

To solve the `ylim` problem I can pass a new argument `ylim` directly in the `plot()` function, something like `df.plot(ylim=(0,2))`, but I still don't get why pandas create an `AxesSubPlot` object for each group. The [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html) is not really helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behavior when plotting a pandas Groupby.

I suggest you use Seaborn, a very good library to plot categorical data, which performs the categorical grouping automatically.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="date", y="Re", hue="region", ax=ax)
```

Seaborn is based on Matplotlib, `fig` and `ax` will be simple Matplotlib Figure and Axes objects, and you can edit them as you please!